# Blazor web app, SetString, raises an exception error message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Exception error occurs on this line

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, value);
```

Exception error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.get returned null.
```

---

Code

```
public class MessageRepository : IMessageRepository
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MessageRepository (IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    //Stores the message in session to pass to another blazor component
    public void SetMessage(string key, string value)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, value);
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the page you linked...

> Additionally, again for security reasons, you must not use
> IHttpContextAccessor within Blazor apps. Blazor apps run outside of
> the context of the ASP.NET Core pipeline. **The HttpContext isn't
> guaranteed to be available within the IHttpContextAccessor**, nor is it
> guaranteed to be holding the context that started the Blazor app.

Comment: I recently ran into this, it appears that it is often best to use the AuthenticationStateProvider.